# Exceptional calls to urllib.request.urlopen when called from ThreadPoolExecutor leaves open file descriptors

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, urllib2, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to download a lot of data using multiple threads from Yahoo Finance. I'm using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` to speed things up. Everything goes well until I consume all the available file descriptors (1024 by default).

When `urllib.request.urlopen()` raises an exception the file descriptor is left open (no matter what timeout for socket I use). Normally this file descriptor is reused if I run stuff only from a single (main) thread so this problem doesn't occur. But when these exceptional `urlopen()` calls are made from `ThreadPoolExecutor` threads these file descriptors are left open. The only solution I have come up with so far is to use either processes (`ProcessPoolExecutor`) which is very cumbersome and inefficient or increase the number of allowed file descriptors to something really big (not all the potential users of my library are going to do this anyway). There must be a smarter way to deal with this problem.

And also I wonder whether this is a bug in Python libraries or am I just doing something wrong...

I'm running Python 3.4.1 on Debian (testing, kernel 3.10-3-amd64).

This is an example code that demonstrates this behaviour:

```
import concurrent
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request
import os
import psutil
from time import sleep


def fetchfun(url):
    urllib.request.urlopen(url)


def main():

    print(os.getpid())
    p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    print(p.get_num_fds())


    # this url doesn't exist
    test_url = 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=YHOOxyz' + \
            '&a=00&b=01&c=1900&d=11&e=31&f=2019&g=d'

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(1) as executor:
        futures = []
        for i in range(100):
            futures.append(executor.submit(fetchfun, test_url))
        count = 0
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            count += 1
            print("{}: {} (ex: {})".format(count, p.get_num_fds(), future.exception()))

    print(os.getpid())
    sleep(60)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `HTTPError` is raised, it saves a reference to the `HTTPResponse` object for the request as the `fp` attribute of the `HTTPError`. That reference gets saved in your `futures` list, which isn't destroyed until your program ends. That means there's a reference to the `HTTPResponse` being kept alive for your entire program. As long as that reference exists, the socket used in the `HTTPResponse` stays open. One way you can work around this is by explicitly closing the `HTTPResponse` when you handle the exception:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(1) as executor:
    futures = []
    for i in range(100):
        futures.append(executor.submit(fetchfun, test_url))
    count = 0
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        count += 1
        exc = future.exception()
        print("{}: {} (ex: {})".format(count, p.get_num_fds(), exc))
        exc.fp.close()  # Close the HTTPResponse
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! This solves the problem! Another solution would have been to use urllib3.